# I have a rpc server, how can I periodically do something too

Tags: ruby, multithreading, server, rpc

```
require 'jimson'
require 'ParseConfig'


class NodeHandler
  extend Jimson::Handler 

  def sum(a,b)
    a + b
    puts a+b
  end
end



server = Jimson::Server.new(NodeHandler.new, 
     :host =>  '127.0.0.1',
     :port =>  8888)
server.start # serve with webrick on http://0.0.0.0:8888/

# def foo(a,b)
   ...
#  end
###I want to call this function each 5s for exmaple
```

I have a rpc server like above. It's really simple now, provides a sum fucntion.
I also need logic such as each 10 s, I call some function called foo().
But now,this server starts and waiting for RPC client message. How can I do the periodical function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'll answer my own question.
I found there is a "works" gem can solve my problem.
I delegate server job to another thread.
By doing this, I can use main thread to do whatever I still want to do.

So I a doing something like this:

```
# Initialize a worker pool.
pool = Workers::Pool.new(:on_exception => proc { |e|
  puts "A worker encountered an exception: #{e.class}: #{e.message}"
})

pool.perform do
  server = Jimson::Server.new(NodeHandler.new, 
     :host =>  '127.0.0.1',
     :port =>  port)
  server.start # serve with webrick on http://0.0.0.0:8999/
end
```